# WordPress query multiple post_types/categories with weighted results

Tags: weighted, wordpress, jquery-pagination

For a WordPress project I'm looking for a better solution to this problem:

The query should get a set of different post_types and taxonomies (like categories), based on the site visitors choice. For example, the user want to get results from normal posts, but also products (from WooCommerce) and other post_types like events and news (both separate post_types. The tricky part is, that the user wants to assign a weight factor to each. So if they select like posts = 1, products = 3, news = 4, they should get a number of posts, three times more products and 4 times more news.

Next step will be to include categories, also with the weight factor, which will make it even more complex, because for posts, I need to query another taxonomy than for products.

The only way I found to solve this, is to run a separate query for each post_type, like fetching 10 items from posts, 30 items from products and 40 from news, to match the weight factors, then combine the results. But this will not scale very well when I need pagination (for example, I want to show 50 entries on the first page, next 50 on second page).

I thought about collecting these single queries into a temporary table, but such a table will be available for the current session only, so it won't help with the pagination (as the temporary table would no longer exist, when the second page is shown).

Does anybody have an idea, how I could approach this task? I would like it according to the WordPress coding standards, so I would like to use WP_Query and the provided filters, because the site is also using geolocating and WPML for translation, so I really would like to avoid writing a low-level query where I have to include all these manually.

I'm not looking for a final solution, just want to collect some ideas.

Comment: Is this for a keyword search where the visitor selects what to search in?

Comment: no keyword search. Basically it's a search by proximity, to find the closest entries to a given location. And maybe later with a price range selection, just for the products.